# cannot use boost::lockfree on ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free

I am string to use `boost::lockfree`. I am using ubuntu 12.04 and have installed `libboost-dev`. I am trying to follow : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html

However seem like I do not have lockfree headers on my system.

How should I install them?

My G++ : g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is quite old, and the standard packages you could install are equally old, so maybe the lockfree library was added in a later version? What version of Boost is installed in your system?

Comment: I actually cannot upgrade my ubuntu as of now, too many working codes. Is there a way to get lockfree working?

Comment: Well that's the problem then, the lockfree library was added in 1.53. It might be possible to download a release of Boost containing the lockfree library and build and install manually. Or set up your packages sources to look at some repository that contains later versions that can still be installed on your system.

Comment: ooh, so simplest way is to download and install boost right?